# Is there a way to keep the floating label highlighted while text is being input in the same box

Tags: autocomplete, material-ui, textfield, box, floating-labels

I am currently working on a phone number field using **Material UI** Components.

The field structure is as follows

```
<Box>
   <Autocomplete />
   <TextField />
</Box>
```

The **Autocomplete** field (used for country code) has a floating label which reads 'Mobile Number'.

When the country code is selected, it is highlighted, however, when the mobile number is to be entered in **TextField**, it is not highlighted anymore.

Is there a way that the floating label can stay highlighted as long as any component within the box is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TextField in Autocomplete takes input props, one of which is InputLabelProps. This controls the highlight and shrink of the label.

InputLabelProps has 2 attributes which control the focus and shrink of the label

```
InputLabelProps: {
 focused: true/false,
 shrink: true/false,
}
```

The value of both attributes is boolean and decides whether the label should be focus or shrink.

The values of these attributes can be controlled using hooks.

```
const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);
```

[This](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-pouuh?file=/demo.js) is an example of how it works for Autocomplete. You can set the value of focus based on certain events.